# Generating epub from xml2rfc programmatically

Tags: python, epub, rfc

I'm using [xml2rfc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xml2rfc/) to write the RFC for [NetJSON](http://netjson.org), I found out it is possible to export the RFC in epub format through the online service [xml2rfc.ietf.org](http://xml2rfc.ietf.org/), but I haven't found an easy way to do this programmatically without using the online service.

I use a script to automatically update the RFC draft in HTML version that is linked on the website, I would really love to do the same for an ePub version, at the moment I do not link the epub version on the website because I have to update it manually, which is time consuming, so I do it sporadically.

Are there any tools that might help me in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[xml2rfc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xml2rfc/) does not support epub, the [webpage](http://xml2rfc.ietf.org/) mentions

> EPub support is provided using version 0.8 of ebook-convert.
>
> PS and RTF support are provided using a combination of wkhtmltopdf, pdf2ps and/or GNU enscript.

You can try libraries like [EbookLib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/EbookLib/0.15) (installed through pip) or you can run [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux) as a process.

**Update:** Actually, it is one-line command after all.

Install calibre (Ubuntu 15.10 in my case):

```
sudo apt-get install calibre
```

Run command ([doc](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/ebook-convert.html)) (this is from epub to other format, but you can do it the other way around)

```
ebook-convert Metamorphosis-jackson.epub something.pdf
```

You can choose from various output formats. (http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/cli/ebook-convert.html#epub-output-options)

---

Output:

```
1% Converting input to HTML...
InputFormatPlugin: EPUB Input running
on /home/<user>/other/xml2rfc/Metamorphosis-jackson.epub
Found HTML cover OEBPS/front-cover.html
Parsing all content...
MediaQuery: Unknown media type "amzn-kf8".
MediaQuery: Unknown media type "amzn-mobi".
MediaQuery: Unknown media type "amzn-mobi".
MediaQuery: Unknown media type "amzn-mobi".
MediaQuery: Unknown media type "amzn-mobi".
MediaQuery: Unknown media type "amzn-mobi".
MediaQuery: Unknown media type "amzn-mobi".
MediaQuery: Unknown media type "amzn-mobi".
MediaQuery: Unknown media type "amzn-mobi".
MediaQuery: Unknown media type "amzn-mobi".
MediaQuery: Unknown media type "amzn-mobi".
34% Running transforms on ebook...
Merging user specified metadata...
Detecting structure...
        Detected chapter: CHAPTER I
        Detected chapter: CHAPTER II
        Detected chapter: CHAPTER III
Flattening CSS and remapping font sizes...
Source base font size is 12.00000pt
Removing fake margins...
Cleaning up manifest...
Trimming unused files from manifest...
Creating PDF Output...
67% Running PDF Output plugin
The cover image has an id != "cover". Renaming to work around bug in Nook Color
71% Rendered title-page.html
76% Rendered copyright.html
81% Rendered table-of-contents.html
85% Rendered pressbooks-promo.html
90% Rendered chapter-001-chapter-i.html
95% Rendered chapter-002-chapter-ii.html
100% Rendered chapter-003-chapter-iii.html
Rendered PDF in 0.915601 seconds:
PDF output written to /home/<user>/other/xml2rfc/something.pdf
Output saved to   /home/<user>/other/xml2rfc/something.pdf
```

Comment: thx, i'm thinking of trying a script that uses their web service to avoid reinventing the wheel

Comment: I see. Well, it depends how robust solution you want. I think that with calibre, you would just run a one line command through Python. Web service may stop working at any time and it seems like an approach requiring more work to me, actually.

Comment: are you sure it's just oneline?